# БархОтка или бАрхотка?

Tags: фонетика

Есть такое украшение - бархотка, представляющее из себя "ошейник" из бархатной ленточки, к которой обычно прикреплен кулон.
Я всегда считала, что нужно говорить "бАрхотка" от слова "бАрхат", но в одном фильме услышала это слово с ударением на О: "бархОтка".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки правильно?

Comment: @august, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Разное ударение в вариантах этого слова соответствует разным написаниям ("барх**о**тка" произносится с ударением на "о"). Не во всех источниках между словами делается смысловое различие, но в некотрых "бархотка" толкуется как разговорная или даже просторечная форма. Для слова "барх**а**тка" находится больше значений (ещё бабочка и цветок). Если судить по тому, в какой последовательности для каждого из слов (в источниках, где они приводятся раздельно) даются их значения, то вариант "бархатка", вероятно, больше связывается с декоративным предметом, в то время как "бархотка" чаще указывает на утилитарное назначение куска материала (чистка обуви, уплотнение в технических устройствах).

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке бАрхатка - это украшение на шею, а бархОтка - кусок ткани для чистки обуви.

Но раньше для названия украшения использовались оба слова:

На Анюте кисейное розовое платье, на шейке черная бархотка с золотеньким медальончиком, ― бабушка подарила! (И. С. Шмелев)

Бархатка эта была прелесть, и дома, глядя в зеркало на свою шею, Кити чувствовала, что эта бархатка говорила (Л. Толстой).